# "program is finished running (dropped off bottom)", with nothing showing up in the text segment

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Trying to get this line of code working in MIPS, but I keep getting this error

```
-- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --
```

and nothing shows up in the 'Text Segment'

```
    .data
main:

li $v0, 10

li $t4,111
li $t5,101
li $t6,50

add $t3, $t4, $t5
sub $t3, $t3, $t6

li $v0, 1
syscall
.text
```

Comment: what's that code supposed to do?

Comment: aren't you suppose to put print value into $a0? `move $a0, $t3` then `li $v0, 1` and then `syscall`?

Comment: and another thing - I would say you messed up `.text` and `.data` order. Should be `.text` segment, then `main:` and rest of the code, then `.data` segment and whatever data you need

Answer (score 2):

Your Main has to be under `.text`, and the line `li $v0, 10` is the syscall number to terminate the program therefore needs to be at the end.

To print your answer you have to you need to call the print function and move your calculated value to the register. Here is a correct running code.

```
.data
.text
.globl main

main:

li $t4,111
li $t5,101
li $t6,50


add $t3, $t4, $t5
sub $t3, $t3, $t6

li $v0, 1          # print int
move $a0, $t3      
syscall

li $v0, 10         # exit
syscall
```